# Use xargs to mv a directory from find results into another directory

Tags: shell, find, xargs, mv

I have the following command:

```
find . -type d -mtime 0 -exec mv {} /path/to/target-dir \;
```

This will move the directory founded to another directory. How can I use `xargs` instead of `exec` to do the same thing.

Comment: Why do you want to use `xargs` instead of `-exec` ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you've got GNU [`mv`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html) (and `find` and `xargs`), you can use the `-t` option to `mv` (and `-print0` for `find` and `-0` for `xargs`):

```
find . -type d -mtime -0 -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /path/to/target-dir
```

---

Note that modern versions of `find` (compatible with POSIX 2008) support `+` in place of `;` and behave roughly the same as `xargs` without using `xargs`:

```
find . -type d -mtime -0 -exec mv -t /path/to/target-dir {} +
```

This makes `find` group convenient numbers of file (directory) names into a single invocation of the program.  You don't have the level of control over the numbers of arguments passed to `mv` that `xargs` provides, but you seldom actually need that anyway.  This still hinges on the `-t` option to GNU `mv`.

Comment: @jlliagre: Have you looked up the meaning of the `-t` option?   It is followed by the target directory name, and means that the last argument is not the target after all, thus enabling exactly this use with `xargs`.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I misread `-t` to be an `xarg` argument instead.

Comment: Great tip. One suggestion - instead of using that messy print0..-0 approach, use xargs -d'\n'

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat: the `-print0` and `-0` approach works even for file names that contain newlines; your alternative does not. Granted, few files have newlines in their names, but the point of the null-terminated notation is that it covers _all_ file names without exception.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I didn't realize filenames could have newlines.

Comment: actually you can controll the number of arguments passed at once to the mv command by using ....xargs -0rn 100 mv....100 is the number of arguments

Answer (score 45):

With [BSD xargs](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/1/xargs/) (for **OS X** and FreeBSD), you can use `-J` which was built for this:

```
find . -name some_pattern -print0 | xargs -0 -J % mv % target_location
```

That would move anything matching `some_pattern` in `.` to `target_location`

With [GNU xargs](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/xargs/) (for **Linux** and Cygwin), use `-I` instead:

```
find . -name some_pattern -print0 | xargs -0 -I % mv % target_location
```

The deprecated `-i` option of GNU xargs implies `-I{}` and can be used as follows:

```
find . -name some_pattern -print0 | xargs -0 -i mv {} target_location
```

Note that BSD xargs also has a `-I` option, but that does something else.

Comment: On Solaris I used: `find . -name some_pattern | xargs -I % mv % target_location`. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "some-dir" -type d -print0 | xargs -0r mv -t x/
```

**find**:
with option `-print0`, the output will end with '\0';

**xargs**:
with option `-0`, it will split args by '\0' but whitespace, `-r` means no-run-if-empty, so you will not get any errors if `find` didn't get any output. (The `-r` is a GNU extension.)

I usually use this in scripts when I'm not sure if the target files exist or not.

Answer (score 2):

`find` is not really a good tool for this. I imagine you want to move all subdirectories into another directory. `find` will output things like

```
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
./a/b/c/d
```

After `./a` gets moved first, you'll just get errors about 'no such file or directory' all the subdirs.

You should just use `mv */ /another/place` -- the trailing slash on the wildcard restricts the expansion to only dirs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using GNU mv, you can use that command:

```
find . -depth -type d -mtime 0 -exec bash -c 'declare -a array;j=1;for i; do array[$j]="$i"; j=$((j+1));done; mv "${array[*]}" /path/to/target-dir' arg0 {} +
```

otherwise, here is a simpler solution that doesn't require xargs:

```
find . -depth -type d -mtime 0 -exec mv -t /path/to/target-dir {} +
```

Note that I added -depth otherwise you'll have errors when both a directory and one of its subdirectory is to be processed.