# How to copy the recent updated multiple files in another directory in Solaris

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris

I want to copy the recently updated multiple file into another directory.

I am having 1.xml,2.xml,3.xml.... in this directory recently someone updated file  or added new file into the directory,So i want to copy those files into the destination directory ..Its like synchronization of 2 directories.

For that I have tried below commend

```
find home/deployment/server/services/ -type f  -mtime 1  | xargs cp  /home/application/
```

and below one also

```
find home/deployment/server/services/ -type f  -mtime 1  -exec cp  /home/application/
```

I am not getting any file into destination after updating 1.xml file,So I have added new file 4.xml even that also not updating in destination directory.

How to process recently updated or newly added multiple files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rsync -aHSP home/deployment/server/services/. /home/application/.` If you don't have `rsync` installed, grab it from sunfreeware...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: 
[use xargs to mv the "find" directory into another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899746/use-xargs-to-mv-the-find-directory-into-another-directory)

Long answer: As I recall (not tested) for **exec** syntax is

```
find . -type f --mtime 1 -exec cp {} /destination/path/ +
```

"{}" is an argument which came from command "find"

For **xargs**

```
find . -type f --mtime 1 | xargs -0 -I {} cp {} /destination/path/
```

Comment: But where it will find you have not defined source here the where i need to run this commend

Comment: xargs: illegal option -- 0
xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]

Answer (score 0):

I do this often but use \; instead of + and usually -cnewer rather than -mtime.

\; executes the cp command on files individually instead of as a group. 
+ executes as a group with as many paths as xterm will take.  It may do this multiple time if there are a lot of files.

the \ in front of the ; option is required or bash will think it is the end of the command.

```
find ./ -mtime -1 -exec cp {} /path/ \; -print
```

Use the -print at the end to get a list of the files that were copied.

Comment: But where it will find u have not defined source here the where i need to run this commend

Comment: I usually run from the folder the files are listed in.  
Try this one:

    find /home/deployment/server/services/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec cp {} /home/application/ \; -print

Comment: find: stat() error home/server/synapse/services/: No such file or directory

Comment: above commoned copying only 1 file not morethan that

Comment: "home/server/synapse/services/" 

This isn't the path I put.   Where did synapse come from?    
Did you mean to use "/home/server/synapse/services" in your find?   The first / is important if you haven't changed directories into the root folder. 
-mtime -1 will only find changes made less than 24 hours ago.  If your files changes are older than that you will need to use a bigger mtime value like -2 (-2 * 24 = any changes in the last 48 hours)